# Create An Object From Dynamic JSON String And Style

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, xml, attributes

I have an example of a string which changes dynamically on my website:

```
"TermsOfService":{"Included":[{"@attributes":{"header":"2 Design Concepts","details":"Unique concepts provided to you"}},{"@attributes":{"header":"Unlimited Revisions","details":"Revise until you are happy"}},{"@attributes":{"header":"Vector Files","details":"Final logo will be in vector file"}},{"@attributes":{"header":"Fast Turnaround","details":"No time wasting. Ready in just five days."}},
```

I'm trying to list all values of **"header"** on my website, to look like this:

- 2 Design Concepts
- Unlimited Revisions
- Vector Files
- Fast Turnaround

This is the code I have, but it doesn't work:

```
<p id="output"></p>
<script>
obj = JSON.parse(text);
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =
obj.Included[1].header;
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to iterate through "Included" array and create DOM-element for every title. Here is example for you: https://jsfiddle.net/k3auo5cn/

Comment: Thanks for this. What if the `var text = ` bit is coming from a different location i.e. domain.com/js/name.js

Comment: Just load that js file before -> <script src="http://domain.com/js/name.js"></script><script> var obj = JSON.parse(text)... </script>